# How to know for which Master a Visio shape belongs to

Tags: visio

I am having difficulty in finding out the master shape for a Visio shape.
Suppose if I drag a Shape named `'Start Shape'` from a Stencil to a document then Visio will create an instance for shape `'Start Shape'` on the Document.

Now I can access the shape name using Name/NameU of the shape property, but using `Name` property I got name as `'Start Shape.12'`

I need to find out the master shape name i.e 'Start Shape' from which the dropped shape is created. In the above case `'Start Shape'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that when you drop a master (shape) from a stencil, Visio creates a local copy of that master in the drawing (you could make those visible using the "Drawing Explorer" window). So when you refer to shape.Master you actually get a reference to that copy.

That means, if later you change the master shape in the stencil, and drop it one more time, you may get another local master (**again with suffix**). This also means that if you rename a master in a stencil, your local master (and thus Shape.Master.Name) will stay unchanged.

To get an "exact" source (if you need to) you may take a look at the "BaseID" and "UniqueID" properties of a master which may be helpful to figure out what was the original master in case it was modified.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem,
through `Shape.Master.Name` property we get the Master Shape Name.